# Is there any way to zoom on the Y-axis inside a stock chart using anychart?

Tags: zooming, stock, anychart, yaxis

I am trying to zoom in and out on the Y-axis using anychart anystock charts.
you could do almost anything with the X-axis ( zooming and toggle grouping on and off etc.. ) but with the Y-axis i could not find anything. 
using other types of charts from anychart some gives the possibilty to zoom on the Y-axis or add a range selector for the Y-axis. but not the stock charts.
any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you for the explanation! You can add custom made scroller for the yScale like this - https://playground.anychart.com/z5YfxrmS/1
Also, you can apply the new yScale min/max value at any moment using the [minimum()](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.scales.Linear#minimum) and [maximum()](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.scales.Linear#maximum) methods of the plot yScale.

Answer (score 0):

The Stock chart doesn't support scroller for Y-scale. The Stock chart provides an auto calculation of the yScale min/max values to provide the best granularity for the visible range of data. It tends to fit the whole series. What is the purpose of the scroller at yScale?

Comment: A yScale scroller would make it easier to interact and to visually analyze the data. especially big amounts of data. of course it would also need the possibility of panning (moving) the chart not only left/right but also up/down.
Is it possibile to manually set the yScale min/max overriding the auto calculation?